# Ormlite for MySql looking for wrong version

Tags: mysql, ormlite-servicestack

We've got a project using Ormlite.MySql built for .NET 4.0.

Ormlite and its dependencies are loaded via NuGet (it's ServiceStack.Ormlite.MySql 3.9.54), including MySql.Data 6.6.5.

When we try to run the code, however, we get a dependency error:

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql package in NuGet lists MySql.Data as a dependency, but doesn't list any specific version. In reflector, I can see that ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql.dll is, in fact, referencing 6.6.4.0 of MySql.Data.dll.

Has anyone encountered this issue? I hate to hack the config file to redirect assmbly binding in general (always feels like a kludge).

Comment: Looking at the MySql site, it doesn't look like 6.6.4 was even a GA release; at least, if it was, they no longer list it on their [list of previous GA releases](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.5.html#downloads)

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered the same problem. I solved it by downloading the Mysql.data.dll version 6.6.4.0 from servicestack on github: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/lib/MySql.Data.dll

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Just install with nuget : Mysql.data (it work for me)
nuget install the right version : "6.6.4" 
(you could verify the version number in the nuget description)